# Use oauth2 to retrieve Google Places client_id

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, oauth-2.0, google-plus, google-places-api

Is it possible to retrieve the Google Places client_id using oauth2? I am able to retrieve Google+ information including the id and Google+ profile url, but I need a way to tie the oauth2 user to the Google Places "client_id".

I have been able to include the Places scope which is listed in the oauth2 popup and asks the user for permission to access the resources, but cannot figure out how to retrieve the authenticated user's client_id.

**Scopes:**

```
var scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me https://maps.google.com/maps/feeds/ https://www.googleapis.com/auth/places';
```

**Google+ API Load**

Although I can successfully retrieve plus data, the places api does not seem to expose any data. Here is what I have tried:

```
function makeApiCall() {
    /* the plus api does retrieve data, but a similar call to places does not
    gapi.client.load('plus', 'v1', function () {
        var request = gapi.client.plus.people.get({
            'userId': 'me'
        });
        request.execute(function (resp) {
            $(".google-signin").find("img").attr('src', resp.image.url).css('height', '32').css('width', '32');
            $("#login-msg").text('Welcome: ' + resp.displayName);
            $("img.vote").css('visibility', 'visible');
        });
    });
    */
    gapi.client.load('places', 'v1', function () {
        debugger
        // the gapi.client does not contain a "places" object 
        var request = gapi.client.places.get({
            'userId': 'me'
        });
        request.execute(function (resp) {
            debugger
        });
    });
}
```

Any clarity on this issue is appreciated.

**CLARIFICATION EDIT**

Perhaps I did not make myself clear. The Google Places API encourages the creation of Events, which are associated with specific Places (of business). We are generating lists based on Google Places API *search* and *details* responses (prototype at top-60.bunkerhill.com follow one or more links)  We would like businesses to be able to add Events to their associated listing, but cannot allow this without first somehow associating the Places Detail response data with a Google Sign-On; or am I missing something important here?

So the question is "Can a user sign-in to any available Google OAuth API that provides some data which can be used to associate the user with a Places Details entry?

Answer (score 1):

The Google Places API is not the same as the G+ API.

Check out https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/ for instructions on accessing Places data (note that you do not use OAuth for this API - you just include the key from developers.google.com/console in your http request).

Comment: Please ignore the previous comment. I have added a clarification of my question and hope you can shed some light on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the clarified question: No, the Places API authentication and authorization for creating Events is only via the developer (and your API key), and never the end user who may interact with your application.

For this specific example, you (the developer) can create Events that are associated with a Place, but it would be incumbent on you to make a further association of which end user you wanted to associate with the creation of that Event, and store that metadata within your application if you cared to do so.

Is there a reason having the Places API itself understand this relationship that would be a benefit to your application?

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. Yes, I think there is great value in supplying an association like the the one supplied for Google+. With our application, after logging-in, we could find the associated Places business (if included on the list) and allow the user to enter their own events or special (time-limited) offers.

Comment: By "find the associated Places", do you mean you also want to search for Places filtered by the logged in user (for example, Places that have Events created by that user?)

Comment: We display a list of 60 Places filtered by "textsearrch" queries, ex. query="plastic+surgeons+in+san+francisco". We currently display any Events assocIated with a given business, but since these Events must be created by our application, we need a way of enabling Google OAuth authenticated users to manage Events for any associated Place entries that are the displayed list of 60. (A link to "Manage Events" would appear on Places entries associated with the logged user.